# Trigger Jenkins builds by pull requsto to specific branch

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I'm using BitbBucket with Jenkins to run builds on Pull Requests.
All pull request are made for two branches master and develop so for every branch have a separate job.

For every job in "Bitbucket Pull Requests Builder" section I have set **BranchesFilter**="s:* d:master" / **BranchesFilter**="s:* d:develop".
From what I understand from the parameter description the build will be trigger for any source branch with merge target is master/develop.
The problem is that for every pull request no matter the target branch the two jobs are triggered.

**Update**

The problem was in the "s:* d:develop" and "s:* d:master" I change it to master and develop it works fine now.

Comment: Your two jobs have the same configuration? I just want to understand if you can use a single job to catch the PR on both branches.

Comment: Yes, they have the same configuration except the branch names master and develop

Comment: Regarding your two PRs, the source branch is the same? It means, if the development is done on BRANCH1 for example, you opened a PR from BRANCH1 to master, and another PR from BRANCH1 to develop. Is it your case?

Comment: Yes, exactly! And I managed to make it work as I want. The problem was in the format of the BranchesFilter so when I set "master"/"develop" without "s:" and "d:" options it worked perfect.

Comment: Cool if you find a solution :) Please post-it here and vote for it.

Answer (score 2):

The solution of the problem was in the "s:* d:develop" and "s:* d:master", I changed it to "master" and "develop" it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar situation.

Set "s: d:develop" instead of "s:* d:develop" and "s: d:master" instead of "s:* d:master"

The problem was in the symbol **"*"**